# Difficult to layout views in Grid layout

Tags: android, android-gridlayout

In my android project, i have a Grid layout with three columns, but when i added views to the grid it is not showing the third column in  the designer. The first column contains a text view ,second column contains a spinner and the third column contains an image view. The width for each of the view is set to "Wrap_content". But the spinner in the second column is taking the remaining space and is pushing the third column out of bounds. here is my xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:numColumns="3"
            app:columnCount="3"
            android:columnWidth="auto_fit"
            app:columnOrderPreserved="true"
            app:orientation="horizontal"
            app:rowOrderPreserved="true">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="@string/title"
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                app:layout_gravity="center"
                app:layout_column="0"
                app:layout_row="0"/>

            <Spinner
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/spinner"
                app:layout_column="1"
                app:layout_row="0"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_astrick"
                app:layout_column="2"
                app:layout_row="0"/>
        </android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>`
```

I have tried giving layout weights to all of the view, but no use.I have attached the preview of the layout. The position of image view is marked in red

[image]

Can anyone tell me a way to properly arrange the views in the grid layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of API 21 the principle of 'weight' was introduced in GridLayout.
[documetation link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html)

> To make a column stretch, make sure all of the components inside it
>   define a weight or a gravity. To prevent a column from stretching,
>   ensure that one of the components in the column does not define a
>   weight or a gravity.

Example from other answer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:grid="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

    android:id="@+id/choice_grid"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:padding="4dp"

    grid:alignmentMode="alignBounds"
    grid:columnCount="2"
    grid:rowOrderPreserved="false"
    grid:useDefaultMargins="true">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
        grid:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="#FF33B5E5"
        android:text="Tile1" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
        grid:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="#FF33B5E5"
        android:text="Tile2" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
        grid:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="#FF33B5E5"
        android:text="Tile3" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
        grid:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="#FF33B5E5"
        android:text="Tile4" />

</android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
```

Comment: For now, try setting up your GridLayout like in the example.

Comment: used the given sample and made changes and now the views are inside but the preview shows nothing other than the text view in the 1st column. when selecting the view in the component tree it is outlining it inside the view

Comment: Did you all give them a equal weight for now? And did you set the width of the widgets inside the GridLayout to `0dp`?

Comment: Yes the width is 0dp and layout_weight is 1